# Camera projection matrix principal point

Tags: opencv, graphics, 3d, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm a little confused about the purpose of adding the offsets of the principal point, in the camera matrix. These equations are from [OpenCV Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

[image]

[image]

[image]

I understand all of this except for adding `c_x` and `c_y`. I've read that we do this in order to shift the origin of the projected point so that it's relative to `(0, 0)`, the top left of the image. However, I don't know how adding the coordinates of the center of the image (the principal point) accomplishes this. I think it's simple geometry, but I'm having a hard time understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Just take a look at the diagram in your question. The x/y coordinate system has its origin somewhere around the center of the image. I.e., there can be negative coordinates. The u/v coordinate system has its origin at the top left corner, i.e., there can be no negative coordinates. For the purpose of this question, I will consider the x/y coordinate system to already be scaled with `fx, fy`, i.e., `(x, y) = (fx * x', fy * y')`.

What you want to do is transform the coordinates from the x/y coordinate system to the u/v coordinate system. Let's look at a few examples:

- The origin in x/y `(0, 0)` will map to `(cx, cy)` in u/v.
- The top left corner (i.e., `(0, 0)` in u/v) has the coordinates `(-cx, -cy)` in x/y.

You could establish many more examples. They all have in common that `(u, v) = (x, y) + (fx, fy)`. And this is the transform stated in the equations.